# ASP.NET postback: where is code-behind method called

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I am new to C# and ASP.NET. I have a jQuery yes/no dialog that calls serverside methods (code-behind) using postback.

I put the code together using some snippets I've found on the internet, but I don't fully understand how the code is working.

If I click "yes" in the jQuery dialog, then the server-side C# method `DeleteConfirmedServerside` is called.

However I don't understand why it works because in the rendered html code I don't see a reference to the server-side method.

I've read some articles about javascript postback... but still I don't understand why the following code works:

`.aspx` file

```
// jQuery code (Dialog with yes/no Buttons)
buttons: [
{
    id: "Yes",
    text: "Yes",

    click: function ()
    {
       $("#btnDeleteConfirmedClientside").click();      
    }
},
....

<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteCanceledClientside"  runat="server"  
     OnClick="DeleteCanceledServerside"  Text="DeleteCanceled"  
     UseSubmitBehavior="false" style="display:none"/>  
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteConfirmedClientside" runat="server"  
     OnClick="DeleteConfirmedServerside" Text="DeleteConfirmed" 
     UseSubmitBehavior="false" style="display:none" />

<div id="myDialog" style="display: none" >
    Do you want to delete this record?
</div>
```

Code-behind (server side)

```
protected void DeleteConfirmedServerside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // called by postback from clientside
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Delete confirmed (YES).')", true);
}
```

Rendered HTML client side:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}

...

<input type="button" name="btnDeleteCanceledClientside" value="DeleteCanceled"   
       onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnDeleteCanceledClientside&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" 
       id="btnDeleteCanceledClientside" style="display:none" />  
<input type="button" name="btnDeleteConfirmedClientside" value="DeleteConfirmed" 
       onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnDeleteConfirmedClientside&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" 
       id="btnDeleteConfirmedClientside" style="display:none" />

<div id="myDialog2" style="display: none" >
    Do you want to delete this record?
</div>
```

If the user clicks "yes" in jQuery dialog, then `btnDeleteConfirmedClientside` is "clicked" and then `__doPostBack(&#39;btnDeleteConfirmedClientside&...)` is called (at least this is what I understand)

What I don't understand is this in the rendered html:

```
onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnDeleteConfirmedClientside&#39;,&#39;&#39;)
```

Why is `__doPostBack` using `btnDeleteConfirmedClientside` and not the server-side code-behind method `DeleteConfirmedServerside`?

`DeleteConfirmedServerside` is called - but how is this happening, since nowhere in the HTML I see a reference to serverside methods... so how is the C# code-behind method `DeleteConfirmedServerside` called ?

Answer (score -1):

The __doPostBack javascript method makes a post back to the server, effectively requesting that your server side method be called.
The hanlding of this HTTP post request is handled behind the scenes and calls your server side method.

If you're new to asp.net, I recommend that you start by having a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc and use asp.net mvc rather than asp.net webforms which is what you're using. MVC is the latest and greatest and has many advantages over webforms.